# Is there a way to use a single Object in Java to run methods from other classes that are inherited?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I came around a question asking to create a single object, in this example, **a** where each time I run the method **eat**, it will print out apple, banana peer, in order, and than cycle back to apple.

I'm pretty sure I need to make 3 classes `class apple` `class banana` `class peer`, each inheriting `class Order` and each has a method `eat()`.

Without using Java primitive types, loops, if statements and only using object oriented features, how can I make this code possible?

```
Order a = new Order();
//a will change state after each method is called.
a.eat(); // Prints "ate apple"
a.eat(); // Prints "ate banana"
a.eat(); // Prints "ate peer"
a.eat(); // Prints "ate apple"
a.eat(); // Prints "ate banana"
a.eat(); // Prints "ate peer"
```

Comment: If you're just creating a single object whose behavior changes each time you call a method, that doesn't really have anything to do with polymorphism, which is about how class inherit behavior from other types.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-state-design-pattern State design pattern but 3 extra classes still required?

Comment: @Evgeniy 3 extra classes is not required. I thought it should be used but could be wrong.

Comment: @Michael Why It's could be wrong? By creating an extra object you will use Polymorphism it's an OOP oriented. If you want to expand it by extra fruit it could be easily done. + You want to have whole logic inside Order NP use states to change behavior then

Answer (score 2):

Since your your state is pure data and doesn't have any behavior associated with it, I think a full state design is overkill for this problem.  I'd suggest the simplest way to do this is with a very basic circular linked list with a fruit in each node.  The `Order` class can just print the data from the current node and then advance to the next on each invocation of `eat()`.

e.g.
given a `Node` and `Order` class like so

```
class Node {
    Node next;
    String data;

    public Node(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }
    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
}
class Order {
    Node node;

    public Order() {
        Node apple = new Node("apple");
        Node banana = new Node("banana");
        Node pear = new Node("pear");

        apple.setNext(banana);
        banana.setNext(pear);
        pear.setNext(apple);

        this.node = apple;
    }

    public void eat() {
        System.out.println(node.getData());
        node = node.getNext();
    }
}
```

you'll get the desired behavior:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Order a = new Order();
    a.eat(); // apple
    a.eat(); // banana
    a.eat(); // pear
    a.eat(); // apple
    a.eat(); // banana
    a.eat(); // pear
}
```